# Download de arquivos da WebView em pasta personalizada

Tags: android

Eu quero que os arquivos que são baixados por meu app que usa WebView fiquem em uma pasta personalizada.
Atualmente está indo para a pasta "Downloads" e queria que fosse para uma pasta com o nome do app e que essa pasta seja criada automaticamente.

```
wb.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                                                    long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                final String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); //This is important!
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); //CATEGORY.OPENABLE
                intent.setType("*/*");//any application,any extension
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Baixando!", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Como faço isso nesse código ai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que é assim:
mude isso:
`request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);`
para
`request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path,filename);`

add:
`File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/NomeDaPasta");`
    ou
`if(!path.exists()) path.mkdir();`

algo assim, procure pela biblioteca `io.FIle` e sobre os métodos`mkdir`, `exist()` e `isDirectory()`.

Comment: deu certo! Obrigado!

Comment: uma boa é dar uma estudada nas bibliotecas de `IO`

Comment: deu certinho, fico muito grato.